# Parsing user input with reads in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am trying to parse user entered string like "A12", into a Haskell tuple, like ('A', 12).

Here's what I have tried:

```
import Data.Maybe

type Pos = (Char, Int)

parse :: String -> Maybe Pos
parse u = do
  (c, rest) <- (listToMaybe.reads) u
  (r, _) <- (listToMaybe.reads) rest
  return $ (c, r)
```

But this always returns Nothing. Why does this happen, and what is the correct way to parse this string? Since this is fairly simple, I'd like to avoid using Parsec or a similar advanced parsing library.

EDIT (to clarify):
Sample Input and Output:

`"A12"` gives `Just ('A', 12)`

`"J5"` gives `Just ('J', 5)`

`"A"` gives `Nothing`

`"2324"` gives `Nothing`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` is usually the opposite of `show` and they both generally use Haskell syntax to represent the given values. This means that since the Haskell syntax for characters uses single quotes, `show` on a character will add single quotes around it, and `read` will expect the single quotes to be there.

In other words, your function expects syntax like `'A' 42`, and indeed it works if you try that:

```
> parse "'A' 42"
Just ('A',42)
```

For your format, I would instead use pattern matching for the first character and then `reads` for the rest, e.g. something like this:

```
parse :: String -> Maybe Pos
parse [] = Nothing
parse (c:rest) = do
  (r, _) <- listToMaybe $ reads rest
  return (c, r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `do` notation? If not, the following function suits your needs. It's not pretty, but it gets the job done.

```
parse :: String -> Maybe Pos
parse (x:xs) = Just (x,read xs::Int)
```

I'm not sure what you consider "failing" and thus worth of a `Nothing`

Comment: Please see the edit in the question that clarifies what I mean.

Also, "read xs::Int" can fail in your answer above creating an exception. In those cases I just want to get a Nothing.